# How can I make sure lambda code gets updated when I upload zip file to S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-cdk-typescript

Currently I'm create a lambda using aws cdk.

Every time I uploaded the lambda code as a zipped file to S3 I manually import it from the console.

I would like the code to be automatically updated everytime I upload the code to the S3 bucket

How can I do so using cdk?

I am aware of the `code:Code.fromBucket()` inside the lambda function props but I'm not sure of what should I enter in the `key` and `objectVersion` parameters and if there should be certain props that I need to configure in the bucket itself

Note :

- I'm using Typescript

Comment: you can zip the file locally and have it deploy by CDK using `Code.fromAsset()` CDK should automatically populate Cloudformation template with S3 bucket, object and version to reference.

Comment: The CDK handles the upload to S3.  Please edit the question with the CDK Lambda construct code you have so far.  Also, consider using the [NodejsFunction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda_nodejs-readme.html) construct.